# alignment issues when using stack views

Tags: swift, view, autolayout, stack, constraints

I have a label in the top left corner that say "Categories", a back button in the bottom left corner.
In the center of of the view is a stack view containing four other stack views. All of them with 3 buttons.

Each time I run it in a simulator the category label in the top left disappears.
I've attached several photos to show current constraints and what my layout should look like and what shows in the simulator.
Thanks
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GNIL.png]
[View in interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw2h3.png)
[Constraints view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0NvG.png)

Answer (score 0):

So it appears it was the image I was using as the "background picture" of each button that was causing my layout issue. I removed it and everything fits now. Thanks